# Bouncing object in Android

Tags: android

I want a program where an object (sphere) falls from top of screen, bounces back few times and settles in the middle of screen. I am new developer in android. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hey, do some research and specific your question, please edit it and add some more details, but generally this is a problem page for SPECIFIC problems not broad ones like that. I guess others would downvote your question! As tip use: AndEngine

Comment: google "android bouncing ball example" or "android bouncing ball tutorial", this site is for specific issues, not full walk-throughs

Answer (score 1):

Well, it has been said already this is not an Android-specific question, but there's an Android-specific answer.
This sample is from [AndEngine's framework examples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/MovingBallExample.java). It will give you an idea how to bounce:

```
        private static class Ball extends AnimatedSprite {
            private final PhysicsHandler mPhysicsHandler;

            public Ball(final float pX, final float pY, final TiledTextureRegion pTextureRegion) {
                    super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion);
                    this.mPhysicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(this);
                    this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
                    if(this.mX < 0) {
                            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(DEMO_VELOCITY);
                    } else if(this.mX + this.getWidth() > CAMERA_WIDTH) {
                            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(-DEMO_VELOCITY);
                    }

                    if(this.mY < 0) {
                            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(DEMO_VELOCITY);
                    } else if(this.mY + this.getHeight() > CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
                            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-DEMO_VELOCITY);
                    }

                    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            }
    }
```